# What to do about unreadable grub screen

Tags: boot, grub2, screen

I have been upgrading my Ubuntu, from 10.04 to 12.04 to 12.10 to 13.04 in the past few days with varying degrees of success.

One problem that has been constant through every step of the upgrade, since 12.04 is that a portion of the text on the grub screen is off the screen to the left so I can't completely make out what the options are.  As I am having other troubles with the upgrade I would like to at least be able to see what options there are to me at boot time.  Is there some sort of grub configuration that can handle this?

Answer (score 1):

My monitor's preferred resolution was 1920x1080, a common 16 x 9 aspect ratio monitor.  This is not supported by vbeinfo (nor are any 16x9 ratios as of Ubuntu 13.04).  You can run vbeinfo from the grub screen after pressing "c".  Uncommenting `GRUB_GFXMODE=640x480` solved it for me.  I don't need more screen res in grub and most monitors support it.